# MySQL Query: Select latest record where column contains certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I have a table that I need to query to obtain the most recent record in which the description contains certain data.  The table columns contain (in part) the following:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| AccountID |    Date    |    Description    |
+-----------+------------+-------------------+
|    125060 | 2006-02-11 | Red Apple         |
|    125060 | 2007-03-23 | Yellow Banana     |
|    125060 | 2009-04-03 | Yellow Apple      |
|    125687 | 2006-03-10 | Red Apple         |
|    139554 | 2007-06-29 | Orange Orange     |
|    139554 | 2009-07-24 | Green Apple       |
|    145227 | 2008-11-22 | Green Pear        |
|    145227 | 2012-04-16 | Yellow Grapefruit |
|    154679 | 2014-05-22 | Purple Grapes     |
|    163751 | 2012-02-11 | Green Apple       |
|    ...    |    ...     |       ...         |
+-----------+------------+-------------------+
```

(There are a few more columns, and hundreds of thousands of records, but this is all I am interested in at the moment)

For this example, I want the most recent record for a subset of AccountIDs that contained "Apple."  The results I am looking for are:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| AccountID |    Date    | Description  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
|    125060 | 2009-04-03 | Yellow Apple |
|    125687 | 2006-03-10 | Red Apple    |
|    139554 | 2009-07-24 | Green Apple  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

The current query I am using is:

```
SELECT AccountID, max(Date), Description 
FROM products
WHERE Description like "%Apple%" and (AccountID=125060 or AccountID=125687 or AccountID=139554)
GROUP BY AccountID;
```

Unfortunately, the results are yielding something to the tune of:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| AccountID |    Date    |    Description    |
+-----------+------------+-------------------+
|    125060 | 2009-04-03 | Red Apple         |
|    125687 | 2006-03-10 | Red Apple         |
|    139554 | 2009-07-24 | Green Apple       |
+-----------+------------+-------------------+
```

where the AccountID is grouping properly, and the appropriate (most recent) date is being selected, but the Description is still returning the FIRST description that matches the WHERE/like clause... and NOT the description that correlates to the record with the selected date.

I've never seen anything like this before.  Is this something I am doing wrong?  I don't have a ton of experience with advanced MySQL queries, but would this be better suited for a left join or inner join on a subquery?

I thought about first using a subquery to pull all records that contain the desired text within the description, and then querying that subquery to select/group by most recent, but didn't know if that would be necessary or not.

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

**UPDATE**
This server host is running an old version of mySQL (4.0.17).  Apparently this version is too old to support subqueries.  Thanks to Shadow and shawnt00 it looks like the same thing is possible with a left join.  Here is the query I am currently using:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM products p1
LEFT JOIN products p2
on p1.AccountID=p2.AccountID and p1.Date<p2.Date and p2.Description like "%Apple%"
where p1.Description like "%Apple%" and p2.Date is null and (p1.AccountID=125060 or p1.AccountID=142580 or p1.AccountID=145135 or p1.AccountID=139254);
```

If any problems present with this query, I will post back.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Since you can not apply a group function you have to join the data back on itself to get the correct description

Comment: This question is asked endlessly. Sometimes it's correctly answered too.

Comment: Please ensure you include the MySQL version in your questions in future - this is especially important if running on very old versions (because as you can see below it wastes a lot of time, yours and ours)

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience Used_By_Already.

As I had said, I am not an experienced coder, and was unaware that it would have such a significant influence.  I will be aware of this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query nothing guarantees that mysql will select those description fields that have the max(date) value. Actually, your version is against the mysql standard and works in mysql under certain configuration settings only.

The solution is to get the max dates by account ids where the description matches the criteria in a subquery and join this back to the table itself using account id and max date:

```
SELECT p.AccountID, p.Date, p.Description
FROM products p
INNER JOIN (SELECT AccountID, max(Date) as maxdate
FROM products
WHERE Description like "%Apple%" and (AccountID=125060 or AccountID=125687 or AccountID=139554)
GROUP BY AccountID) t
ON p.AccountID=t.AccountID and p.Date=t.maxdate
WHERE Description like "%Apple%";
```

**UPDATE**

Mysql v4.0 does not support subqueries, therefore the above method is not applicable. You can still use a left join approach, where you self join the products table and use the is null expression to find those dates for which larger dates do not belong to:

```
select p1.*
from products p1
left join products p2
on p1.accountid=p2.accountid and p1.date<p2.date
where Description like "%Apple%" and p2.date is null;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT AccountID, max(Date) as maxdate
FROM products

This is similar to the error I was getting any time I tried to create an inline subquery.  Could this be a MySQL version issue?  The database host is using an old version (4.0.17).
WH...

Comment: Subquery support was added in mysql v4.1

Comment: `code`
    SELECT p.AccountID, p.Date, p.Description
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN (SELECT AccountID, max(Date) as maxdate
    FROM products
    WHERE Description like "%Apple%" and (AccountID=125060 or AccountID=142580 or AccountID=145135 or AccountID=139254)
    GROUP BY AccountID) t
    ON p.AccountID=t.AccountID and p.Date=t.maxdate
    WHERE Description like "%Apple%";

(sorry, I don't know how to get the query to format properly in a code block inside of a comment)

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a solution that does not use subqueries.

Comment: @Shadow You need `p2.date is null` in the `where` clause not the join condition.

Comment: Thanks for the continued efforts and information here shadow and others.  This query is missing the acctid criteria, so my updated query is as follows:

Comment: select p1.*
from products p1
left join products p2
on p1.AccountID=p2.AccountID and p1.Date<p2.Date
where p1.Description like "%Apple%" and p2.Date is null and (p1.AccountID=125060 or p1.AccountID=142580 or p1.AccountID=145135 or p1.AccountID=139254);

Comment: Will it blow up with the description filter in the join condition too? I guess that needs to be there also.

Comment: And now, it does return only the latest record... HOWEVER, it seems that if the most recent record does not contain the LIKE criteria, it doesn't return any row with that AccountID in the query results.  I was having this problem when I attempted a left join to being with, which is why I tried switching over to a group by subquery... which now at least I know is not feasible due to the verions of MySQL I'm locked into.  Is there something I've done wrong with the additional AccountIDs in the query string that would cause records to be excluded?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion shawnt00.  That may have done it.  Here is the current query:

Comment: select p1.*
from products p1
left join products p2
on p1.AccountID=p2.AccountID and p1.Date<p2.Date and p2.Description like "%Apple%"
where p1.Description like "%Apple%" and p2.Date is null and (p1.AccountID=125060 or p1.AccountID=142580 or p1.AccountID=145135 or p1.AccountID=139254);

Comment: it seems to be returning all records properly now (at least for the simple test query that I ran).  I will have to play with a few more to be sure, but please let me know if you spot any errors in the query otherwise.  Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your old MySQL can handle this version. It combines the `AccountID` and `Date` values into a single result that works with `in`.

```
select
    p.Account, p.Date, p.Description
from
    products p
where
        p.AccountID in (125060, 125687, 139554)
    and p.Description like '%Apples%'
    and concat(cast(p.AccountID as varchar(8)), date_format(p.Date, '%Y%m%d')) in
    (
        select concat(cast(p2.AccountID as varchar(8)), date_format(max(p2.Date), '%Y%m%d'))
        from products p2
        where p2.Description like '%Apple%'
        group by p2.AccountID
    )
```

Many platforms could handle this kind of subquery before they could work with "derived tables" and "inline views" in the `from` clause. I'm not sure about MySQL though.

Comment: yikes... I'd rather recommend an upgrade :) but "if needs must"

Comment: No, mysql could not handle any subqueries before v4.1

Comment: @Shadow I've always been frustrated by the varying terminology across systems so I never knew what that meant. (I just tried a quick Goodle search.) And I also find it hard to imagine getting up to version 4 without them. I guess a temp table is the next option??

Comment: Tell me about it, I started to use mysql v4.0.20. It was frustrating. However, there is a self join approach that you can still use to get the latest recrd's data without subqueries. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Shadow yeah, I had forgotten about the self join until I glanced below.

Answer (score 0):

"*returning the FIRST description that matches the WHERE/like clause... and NOT the description that correlates to the record with the selected date*"

That is because you are relying on a feature in MySQL called an "extension" to GROUP BY. This "feature" allows you to include only the `AccountID` in the group by clause; BUT the column `Description` is not mentioned. So MySQL chooses "**any value**" in the MuSQL documentation:

> MySQL extends the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. T**he server is free to choose any value from each group**, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. 
>   see: [12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) bold emphasis added

In brief the result you are getting in the Description column you cannot control by your current query.

IF your version supported sub-queries these would assist:

```
SELECT
      p.*
FROM products p
      INNER JOIN (

            SELECT
                  AccountID
                , MAX(`date`) AS dt
            FROM products
            WHERE Description LIKE '%Apple%'
                  AND (AccountID = 125060
                  OR AccountID = 125687
                  OR AccountID = 139554)
            GROUP BY
                  AccountID
      ) m ON p.AccountID = m.AccountID
                  AND p.`date` = m.dt
/* and if required */
WHERE p.descrption LIKE '%Apple%'
;
```

An alternative for MySQL that so far does not support ROW_NUMBER() is to mimic that function as follows: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9202a/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
    (`AccountID` int, `Date` datetime, `Description` varchar(17))
;

INSERT INTO Products
    (`AccountID`, `Date`, `Description`)
VALUES
    (125060, '2006-02-11 00:00:00', 'Red Apple'),
    (125060, '2007-03-23 00:00:00', 'Yellow Banana'),
    (125060, '2009-04-03 00:00:00', 'Yellow Apple'),
    (125687, '2006-03-10 00:00:00', 'Red Apple'),
    (139554, '2007-06-29 00:00:00', 'Orange Orange'),
    (139554, '2009-07-24 00:00:00', 'Green Apple'),
    (145227, '2008-11-22 00:00:00', 'Green Pear'),
    (145227, '2012-04-16 00:00:00', 'Yellow Grapefruit'),
    (154679, '2014-05-22 00:00:00', 'Purple Grapes'),
    (163751, '2012-02-11 00:00:00', 'Green Apple')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      p.AccountID, p.Date, p.Description
FROM (
      SELECT
             @row_number:= case when @acct = pr.AccountID then @row_number + 1 else 1 end as rownumber
           , @acct := pr.AccountID as acct
           , pr.AccountID, pr.Date, pr.Description
      FROM products pr
      CROSS JOIN (select @row_number := 0, @acct := '') as rn
      WHERE Description LIKE '%Apple%'
             AND (AccountID = 125060
             OR AccountID = 125687
             OR AccountID = 139554)
      ORDER BY pr.AccountID, pr.Date DESC
      ) p
WHERE p.rownumber = 1
ORDER BY p.AccountID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9202a/4/0)**:

```
| AccountID |                    Date |  Description |
|-----------|-------------------------|--------------|
|    125060 | April, 03 2009 00:00:00 | Yellow Apple |
|    125687 | March, 10 2006 00:00:00 |    Red Apple |
|    139554 |  July, 24 2009 00:00:00 |  Green Apple |
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. You have to filter on the description in the outer query as well, since the same account id may have products which do not contain the word apple with the same date. And then your query will match mine.

Comment: I wasn't attempting to match yours, but your point is valid and I have made the change, thanks. My major focus was on the bogus nature of the group by extension. There is an alternative approach of course which is to mimic the use of row_number()

Answer (score 0):

First group by the most recent date and then join it with your product table by date and accountId. The where come outside if you want more statements for the product table.

```
SELECT 
    P.*
FROM products P INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        AccountID,
        MAX(Date) MostRecentDate    
    FROM products       
    WHERE Description LIKE '%Apple%' AND P.AccountID IN (125060 , 125687, 139554)
    GROUP BY AccountID
) MR ON MR.AccountID = P.AccountID AND MR.MostRecentDate = P.Date
```

Comment: This is not correct. You do not filter on the description field in your subquery, therefore the max(date) will return the last date regardless whether that matches the description or not.

Comment: Yes it is correct beceause the filter is outside and the inner join makes the where clause. It's easy to read, faster and uses the index, also you can add more filters outside (in the WHERE CLAUSE). I've made the table and prove it by my own. It's unfair you put a minus -1.  Your answer is repetitive, uses more resources and more difficult to understand.

Comment: 1. No, it is incorrect. If you have a record for the same account id with later date with a description not containing apple, and an earlier one where the description contains the word apple, then your subquery returns the date for the record without the word apple. Since you filter for the keyword in the outer query, this particular account id will not even appear in your results. 2 . My answer preceeded yours by 20 minutes, so cannot be repetitive.

Comment: Ok, it must be only inside and not outside too. That's what i mean with repetitive, it's redundant. I made change to the data and it works. Thank you for your observation, you don't need to put not useful answer, just comment.

Comment: It remains inefficient until you do all the filtering inside the subquery. Shadow will also argue that the filter on description is also required after the subquery which on the basis of the sample data is most probably correct (but might be redundant if the time-stamping is more precise than displayed in the sample data).